# проверка url на наличии якоря и сравнение с id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть ресторан с меню. У карточки блюд есть id. Задача - переходим в меню ресторана по ссылке с якорем и данное блюдо подсвечивается. Т.е. я проверяю ссылку на наличие якоря. Затем проверяю anchor(якорь ссылки) соответствует регулярному выражению anchor_ЛЮБОЕКОЛИЧЕСТВОЦИФР_dish, как в ID блюда. Если соответствует, подсвечиваю блюдо.
Вот мой код:

```
var Anchor = $(location).attr('hash'),
        idFood = $('#'+ Anchor);
    if (Anchor.match(/anchor_\d+_dish/i)) {
        idFood.css('outline', '3px solid #9cc95b');
    }else {
        idFood.css('outline', 'none');
    };`
```

Все работает. Но если меняется ссылка, например "/link#categoray"(внутри данной страницы без перезагрузки), эта часть кода не срабатывает

```
else {
        idFood.css('outline', 'none');
    };`
```

я так понимаю, что это из-за hash? Можете подсказать как можно переделать?

Comment: А почему вы не используете псевдокласс :target?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const foo = () => {
    const { hash } = location
    console.log('hashchange', { hash })
}
window.addEventListener('hashchange', foo)
window.addEventListener('load', foo)
```

```html
<a href="#1">1</a><br>
<a href="#2">2</a><br>
<a href="#3">3</a><br>
```

Comment: а если конкретно на моем примере? не соображу как аналогично сделать

Comment: во первых - необходимо добавить в вопрос метку JQuery 2) пойти и погуглить `$.on` 3) сказать мне спасибо ; )

Comment: Благодарю)
"2) пойти и погуглить $.on" - можно конкретнее?

Comment: что-то вроде этого `window.addEventListener('hashchange', foo)` = `$(window).on("hashchange",foo)` https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: `const { hash } = location` = `const hash = location.hash`